# adicionar informações no banco de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sqlite, lista

Queria saber se é possível ter uma lista em banco de dados, como no java `List<>`
como na imagem abaixo,
uma tabela `comida` que pode ter um ou mais `ingredientes`.
Como posso fazer isso no banco de dados?

[image]

por exemplo, adicionar mai um ingrediente em lasanha, e mais 2 em macarronada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode *Adicionar* os ingredientes utilizando o **UPDATE**, por exemplo:

```
UPDATE SUA_TABELA
SET INGREDIENTES = INGREDIENTES + ', novoIngrediente'
```

Vamos supor que queira adicionar queijo ao prato Lasanha:

```
UPDATE SUA_TABELA
SET INGREDIENTES = INGREDIENTES + ', queijo' // Aqui você vai concatenar o(s) ingrediente(s) que já tem com o novo
WHERE código_prato = 1
```

O resultado seria:

```
|  1   | lasanha | massa, queijo |
```